# How to add and remove items in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a logic where we click a button and save an ID in localStorage. We could have 2 ids max. However, we can also remove an ID from it and add a new one. Finally, we cannot add more than 2 and these ids must be unique. These IDs will be then set as an input value in a form.

So I have four steps page:

- Homepage page
- Search result page
- Single article page
- Form result page

Each page has:

```
<form id="post_form_id" method="post" action="/test/compare/"> 
   <input id="input_post_id" type="hidden" name="varPostId" value=""> 
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link nav-link" id="jikubox"></i> 
   <span class="badge badge-secondary">0</span></button>
</form>
```

Saved IDs will be set in `name="varPostId" value=""`

Now the tricky part which is confusing me, so localStorage can only have `strings` so first of all on **each page load** I do:

```
var lines = localStorage.getItem("lines") ? 
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : [];
```

Then since in the **article page** I have a `save button` to add the current article id in the array, I do:

```
<button type="button" class="save_post">SAVE</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".save_post").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if (localStorage.getItem("attempts") >= 2) { 
    alert('nope'); 
    return; 
  } else {

  // Here I set the id for each article which I saved before via php in a span 
    var thisId = $(".my_post_id").attr("data-id");

    var lines = localStorage.getItem("lines") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")) : []; 
    lines.push(thisId);
    localStorage.setItem("lines", JSON.stringify(lines));
    console.log(lines);
    $("#input_post_id").val(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")));
    var attempts = Number(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
    localStorage.setItem("attempts", ++attempts);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
    $("#jikubox span").text(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
  }
});
```

Notice I have another localStorage: `attempts`, that is used to add or remove a number I set in a counter badge, basically an indicator which tells how many items I have in my "***bag***". **Remember: max 2 and unique.**

So finally on the ***form result page*** I have a button to remove added items and the following js is used:

```
$(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){

  // Here I set the id for each article, I do that with php
  // <span  class="removeId" data-thisPostId="<?php echo $idThisPost; ?>"></span>

  var removeThisId = $(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId");
  $(this).parent().fadeOut();
  var attempts = Number(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
  localStorage.setItem("attempts", --attempts);
  $("#jikubox span").text(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
  lines.splice($.inArray(removeThisId, lines), 1);
  localStorage.getItem("lines", lines); 
  localStorage.setItem("lines", lines); 
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("lines"));
});
```

The logic is kinda ok but after I try few times, I eventually get empty `lines` `array` and the ids are not set to the `input value`. I think I over complicated the logic and I was wondering where and how I could simplify and correct it. I am looking into a single general bit of code which handles all of this without complicating the logic.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to an answer, one bit of code has been simplified and the `counter` will be set by checking the length of the ids in `lines array` so We can **remove** the whole code for the `attempts local storage` logic

```
$("#jikubox span").text(lines.length);
```

Comment: @Teemu yes indeed, the values of `lines array`, will be inserted in the input value like `<input type="text" value="242, 248">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you store your IDs in an array-

```
var idList=["123","456"];
```

You can store IDs like this -

```
localStorage.setItem("idList",JSON.stringify(idList));
```

and fetch idList like this-

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("idList")).length
```

Just make sure to put validations all around.

P.S. No need to count the "attempts" as you can anytime use the below code to find the length of the idList, which can be 2 or any number you want

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("idList")).length
```

---

**UPDATE:**

To remove IDs-

```
function removeId(array, element) {
    const index = array.indexOf(element);
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Fetch array from localStorage and pass it into this function -

```
idList  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("idList"))
```

and call the function like this -

```
 removeId(idList,idToBeDeleted)
```

Comment: OK true in regards of `attempts`, actually that is a superb advise. However, "_**Assume you store your IDs in an array**_" yeah well, these ids would be set on the save button click into the localStorage from which I could also need to be able to remove, so they are not added with php, therefore I need a general logic

Comment: excelelnt, one part of the code has been simplified,   ` $("#jikubox span").text(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")).length);`, i guess i need to also set this on each page load. Yet the other logic is missing, add/remove on lines and set input value with it

Comment: question updated with your suggestion for the counter bit, the other part of the issue is remaining tho

Comment: updated the answer with remove logic. Let me know if you face any issues. Just put validations all around according to your scenario.

Comment: hey thanks, just checking it. Currently I am doing this for the counter `$("#jikubox span").text(lines.length);` but then when I do `$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
      if (lines.length >= 2) { 
        alert('nope'); 
        return; 
      } else {.. ` I get `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: ok counter resolved by doing `var counter = lines.length;` and then  `if (counter >= 2) { 
        alert('nope'); 
        return; 
      } else {` now will check your solution for add/remove

Comment: Before accessing the `.length` on an array make sure it exists.
something like `if(lines && lines.length >2)` 
Also your condition is not valid as the `.length` will return the number of elements in the array i.e. 2.  So  your code `if (lines.length >= 2) { alert('nope'); return; }` won't work as expected and will pop up alert when you'll have 2 elements in the array

Comment: so in regards of remove this is what I am doing on a remove button click     `removeId(lines, removeThisId)
    localStorage.getItem("lines", lines); 
    localStorage.setItem("lines", lines); ` correct?

Comment: yeah, it looks good. Just don't forget to put validations according to the scenario.

Comment: actually if I do  `$(".save_post").on("click", function() {
      if(lines && lines.length > 2) {
        alert('nope');` will add 3, should it not be `>=` ?

Comment: this is keep adding numbers to the counter  `if(lines && lines.length >= 2) {` while this was working `if (lines.length >= 2) { alert`

Comment: @rob.m were you able to figure out the solution ?

Comment: I cannot use the remove function, i tried `function removeId(array, element) { const index = lines.indexOf(element); lines.splice(index, 1);
  } $(".removeJiku").on("click", function(){ var removeThisId = $(".removeId").attr("data-thisPostId"); $("#usp-custom-2").val($("#usp-custom-2").val().replace(removeThisId,'').replace(",",''));
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(); removeId(lines, removeThisId);
    $("#input_post_id").val(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("lines")));
    $("#jikubox span").text(lines.length); $("#usp-form-253 #usp-title").val(" "); console.log(lines); });`

Answer (score 1):

This block isn't doing what you want:

```
lines.splice($.inArray(removeThisId, lines), 1);
localStorage.getItem("lines", lines); 
localStorage.setItem("lines", lines);
```

The second line is getting something from localStorage but isn't doing anything with it. It could be the equivalent of

```
lines.splice($.inArray(removeThisId, lines), 1);
['one line', 'another line'];
localStorage.setItem("lines", lines);
```

Just some random value that proceeds to get ignored by the interpreter.

The other problem is that you're setting `localStorage.lines` to the plain `lines` variable, *not to* `JSON.stringify(lines)`.

Note that you can simplify your syntax noise just by doing

```
localStorage.lines = JSON.stringify(lines);
```

and

```
const lines = JSON.parse(localStorage.lines || '[]');
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this. So this would explain what mistakes I'm doing, what's the solution tho?

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem('item')` only accepts one parameter, which will return the value if it exists in the local storage and will return `null` item doesn't exist.

`localStorage.setItem(item, value)` accepts two parameters. item which is a key and the value which is to be saved for the key. If item is already set it will overwrite the value.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this. So this would explain what mistakes I'm doing, what's the solution tho?